# How to run a Julia script in Atom

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I just found the [Atom text editor](https://atom.io) on OSX.

When I try to run a Julia script in Atom, like in [Juno](http://junolab.org), I get a path error:

[image]

Changing my path by editing `~/.profile` doesn't work... How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Atom --> Open Your Init Script

[image]

There, in the init.coffee file, put this:

```
process.env.PATH = ["/Applications/Julia-0.4.0-dev-a9e0dd2fb2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin",
 process.env.PATH].join(":")
```

and it should run when you do <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Should we us "julia-ide package" or "julia-client package"?

Comment: @skan I've only used julia-client... not sure about julia-ide. Pretty sure julia-client requires julia 0.4 (or higher) though.